# Unknown Symbol on an Atomic Bomb

Tags: world-war-two, nuclear-weapons

A 1997 czech movie [Knoflíkáři](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0128292/?ref_=nv_sr_1) depicts a "Fat Man" atomic bomb that should have been dropped on Kokura town, but the target has been changed to Nagasaki for a bad weather conditions (which is historically correct).

The image of the bomb itself is not so accurate. What interests me is the triangular symbol on the bomb. I can't find its meaning anywhere. **Is the symbol purely fictitious or does it have any meaning?**

[image]

Comment: This might belong on movies.stackexchange.com.

Comment: An answer could establish that it has meaning, but no answer can establish that it has no meaning.

Comment: Okay I will put it in Movies community - I just hope they won't say it belongs to History community :( There is also much less probability someone will know an answer there... and I searched through all communities and have not found better one.

Answer (score 4):

The bomb depicted is of the "[Little Boy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little_Boy)" type, **not** the "[Fat Man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fat_Man)" type. (Note the elongated form -- "Fat Man" was more rounded.) So we're looking at the Hiroshima bomb, not the Nagasaki one. (Quite a slipup by the movie producers...)

[This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little_Boy#/media/File:Atombombe_Little_Boy_2.jpg) is a picture of "Little Boy" directly prior to being loaded into *Enola Gay*. *There are no such markings on the bomb*, indeed there are various differences (external fastenings, cables, bolts etc.) between what was loaded into *Enola Gay* and what is pictured in the question.

So, while the symbol might have a meaning *somewhere*, it has none with regards to "Little Boy", because *it was not on "Little Boy"*.

Comment: I know the shape of the bomb is incorrect but the movie was about Kokura/Nagasaki, so I came from that. Anyway, that's irrelevant - I care just about the symbol.